# How to test an Electron app with selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, electron, e2e-testing

I have read the documentation and I have followed the tutorial step by step and I only have managed to run the app.

- Documentation: http://electron.atom.io/docs/tutorial/using-selenium-and-webdriver/

The connection with chromedriver I cannot make it work, when I launch the test and try click a simple button I get this:

> Error: ChromeDriver did not start within 5000ms   at Error (native)
>   at node_modules/spectron/lib/chrome-driver.js:58:25   at
>   Request._callback (node_modules/spectron/lib/chrome-driver.js:116:45) 
>   at Request.self.callback
>   (node_modules/spectron/node_modules/request/request.js:200:22)   at
>   Request.
>   (node_modules/spectron/node_modules/request/request.js:1067:10)   at
>   IncomingMessage.
>   (node_modules/spectron/node_modules/request/request.js:988:12)   at
>   endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:913:12)   at _combinedTickCallback
>   (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)   at process._tickCallback
>   (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)

My code:

```
"use strict";
require("co-mocha");
var Application = require('spectron').Application;
var assert = require('assert');

const webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');

const driver = new webdriver.Builder()
  .usingServer('http://127.0.0.1:9515')
  .withCapabilities({
    chromeOptions: {
      binary: "./appPath/app"
    }
  })
  .forBrowser('electron')
  .build();

describe('Application launch', function () {
  this.timeout(100000);
  var app;
  beforeEach(function () {
    app = new Application({
      path: "./appPath/app"
    });
    return app.start();
  });

  afterEach(function () {
    if (app && app.isRunning()) {
      return app.stop();
    }
  });

  it('click a button', function* () {
    yield driver.sleep(5000);
    yield driver.findElement(webdriver.By.css(".classSelector")).click();
  });
});
```

Thanks and sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, Spectron (which is a wrapper for WebdriverIO) and WebdriverJS (which is part of Selenium-Webdriver) are two different frameworks, you only need to use one of them for your tests.

If you are using WebdriverJS, then you need to run `./node_modules/.bin/chromedriver` in this step: http://electron.atom.io/docs/tutorial/using-selenium-and-webdriver/#start-chromedriver

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use [Spectron](https://github.com/electron/spectron). which is a less painful way of testing your electron app. in my opinion perfect combination is using it with [Ava](https://github.com/avajs/ava) test framework, which allows the concurrently test.

`async & await` is also another big win. which allows you to have so clean test cases.

and also if you have a test which needs to happen serial, you can use `test.serial`

```js
test.serial('login as new user', async t => {
  let app = t.context.app
  app = await loginNewUser(app)
  await util.screenshotCreateOrCompare(app, t, 'new-user-mission-view-empty')
})
    
test.serial('Can Navigate to Preference Page', async t => {
  let app = t.context.app
  await app.client.click('[data-test="preference-button"]')
  await util.screenshotCreateOrCompare(app, t, 'new-user-preference-page-empty')
})
```

and just for reference; my helper test cases.

```js
test.before(async t => {
  app = util.createApp()
  app = await util.waitForLoad(app, t)
})

test.beforeEach(async t => {
  t.context.app = app
})

test.afterEach(async t => {
  console.log('test complete')
})
// CleanUp
test.after.always(async t => {
  // This runs after each test and other test hooks, even if they 
 failed
  await app.client.localStorage('DELETE', 'user')
  console.log('delete all files')
  const clean = await exec('rm -rf /tmp/DesktopTest')
  await clean.stdout.on('data', data => {
    console.log(util.format('clean', data))
  })
  await app.client.close()
  await app.stop()
})
```

util function,

```
    // Returns a promise that resolves to a Spectron Application once the app has loaded.
    // Takes a Ava test. Makes some basic assertions to verify that the app loaded correctly.
    function createApp (t) {
      return new Application({
        path: path.join(__dirname, '..', 'node_modules', '.bin',
          'electron' + (process.platform === 'win32' ? '.cmd' : '')),

        // args: ['-r', path.join(__dirname, 'mocks.js'), path.join(__dirname, '..')],
        env: {NODE_ENV: 'test'},
        waitTimeout: 10e3
      })
    }
```

Comment: Spectron is officially deprecated as of February 1, 2022.

Answer (score 0):

I could get ChromeDriver working by adding a proxy exception in my terminal.

```
export {no_proxy,NO_PROXY}="127.0.0.1"
```